# Characters Populating in DropDownList of Countries using external Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Dropdown is giving back the result of list of countries as shown in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxQP.png 
Web Service is taken from `http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL`
I am using the Method of GetCountries only. 
My coding is as under,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace WebServices
{
    public partial class GetCountries : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient client =  new ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = client.GetCountries();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @Rohit this http://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxQP.png

Comment: @Rohit Image is added ... showing the result in dropdown which is giving back result in character by character

Comment: this is asmx/XML file from where I am trying to populate just country names in my dropdown, how would I know that which is DataValueField and DataTextField http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries

Comment: Please post the exact problem and post only necessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the drop down list's datatext field and datavalue field. 
You can either set it in the code or aspx page.
Also you should not set the data source in the pageload directly. You should put it inside a `!page.isPostBack`

Since you are getting the response as XML, You could use Linq-to-XML to get a collection of the values you want from the xml tree and bind that to your dropdownlist. see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

OP solved his problem with the following lines of code (based on his comment)

`var xml = client.GetCountries(); 
var countries = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Name").Select(arg => arg.Value).ToList();
DropDownList1.DataSource = countries; DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: Iam using another's Web Service, How would I know that, what datatextfield and datavalue field is assigned to

Comment: Use quick watch or assign it to some var and see

Comment: If you are getting your data as XML then you might have to convert it into a datatable or IEnumerable

Comment: done with this. `var xml = client.GetCountries();
                var countries = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Name").Select(arg => arg.Value).ToList();
                DropDownList1.DataSource = countries;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: Happy to help be of help @Qadeer